Oracle APEX - How to fill a Display Only type item with text depending on what I select in 3 Select List type items?
I am new to using Oracle APEX 23.2.3 and I am trying to do the following:
I have 3 items of type Select List (Opportunity, Periodicity, Automation). Each one obtains the list of values from an SQL query. For example, for Opportunity:
select OPPORTUNITY, OPPORTUNITY_ID
from OPPORTUNITY

After selecting a value in the 3 Select Lists, I need an item of type Display Only to be filled with a value that exists in a table named Effectiveness, this table is similar to the following:



ID
Opportunity
Periodicity
Automation
Effectiveness




1
preventivo
permanente
manual
regular


2
correctivo
periodico
automatizado
optimo


3
detectivo
ocasional
semi-auto
bueno



To do this, I have created a Dynamic Action that executes the following JavaScript code:
var op_apl = ($v("P14_Opportunity") !== "") ? parseInt($v("P14_Opportunity")) : 0;
var per_apl = ($v("P14_Periodicity") !== "") ? parseInt($v("P14_Periodicity")) : 0;
var aut_ctrl = ($v("P14_Automation") !== "") ? parseInt($v("P14_Automation")) : 0;
var ef_ctrl = "";

if (!isNaN(op_apl) && !isNaN(per_apl) && !isNaN(aut_ctrl)) { 
    apex.server.process("GET_EFFECTIVENESS", {
        x01: op_apl,
        x02: per_apl,
    x03: aut_ctrl
    }, {
    dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {            
        if(data.effectiveness) {
            ef_ctrl = data.effectiveness; 
            $s("P14_EFFECTIVENESS", ef_ctrl); 
            } else {
            console.error("No effectiveness was found for the given values.");
        }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("Error when obtaining control effectiveness:", errorThrown);
        }
    });
}


In my variables op_apl, per_apl and aut_ctrl I am receiving the ID of each row and not the field with text, so in the AJAX callback (GET_EFFECTIVENESS) I am executing the following PL/SQL code:
DECLARE
     l_ef_control VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
     SELECT EFFECTIVENESS
     INTO l_ef_control
     FROM EFFECTIVENESS
     WHERE OPPORTUNITY = (SELECT OPPORTUNITY
                         FROM OPPORTUNITY
                         WHERE OPPORTUNITY_ID = APEX_APPLICATION.G_X01)
     AND PERIODICITY = (SELECT PERIODICITY
                       FROM PERIODICITY
                       WHERE PERIODICITY_ID = APEX_APPLICATION.G_X02)
     AND AUTOMATION = (SELECT AUTOMATION
                      FROM AUTOMATION
                      WHERE AUTOMATION_ID = APEX_APPLICATION.G_X03);

     APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('effectiveness', l_ef_control);
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
END;

However, when I run the application I fill the Select List items, but the Display Only item is not filled with any data. In the web browser console I can see the following error:
No effectiveness was found for the given values.
Could someone guide me or help me resolve my error? Maybe what I'm trying to do is not the right way.
Thank you so much.

You could simplify this with a dynamic action of the type "set value" and a set value type of SQL. Apex can handle the ajax and json for you then.

First of all, In my opinion, the data structure you have, is not well designed. You may need to re-structure it for example using foreign keys, unique keys and defining relation between tables more concretely. (Link)
And for your problem, in your Javascript code if(data.effectiveness) you are trying to check a boolean value (true/false). But in your AJAX process,
you are returning a value like 'optimo' if I understood it correctly.
So, I suggest you to change your Javascript code and AJAX process as:
DECLARE
     l_ef_control VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
     SELECT EFFECTIVENESS
     INTO l_ef_control
     FROM EFFECTIVENESS
     WHERE OPPORTUNITY = (SELECT OPPORTUNITY
                         FROM OPPORTUNITY
                         WHERE OPPORTUNITY_ID = APEX_APPLICATION.G_X01)
     AND PERIODICITY = (SELECT PERIODICITY
                       FROM PERIODICITY
                       WHERE PERIODICITY_ID = APEX_APPLICATION.G_X02)
     AND AUTOMATION = (SELECT AUTOMATION
                      FROM AUTOMATION
                      WHERE AUTOMATION_ID = APEX_APPLICATION.G_X03);

     APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('effectiveness', true);
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('value', l_ef_control);
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('effectiveness', false);
     APEX_JSON.WRITE('value','Something went wrong!');
     APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
END;

var op_apl = ($v("P14_Opportunity") !== "") ? parseInt($v("P14_Opportunity")) : 0;
var per_apl = ($v("P14_Periodicity") !== "") ? parseInt($v("P14_Periodicity")) : 0;
var aut_ctrl = ($v("P14_Automation") !== "") ? parseInt($v("P14_Automation")) : 0;
var ef_ctrl = "";

if (!isNaN(op_apl) && !isNaN(per_apl) && !isNaN(aut_ctrl)) { 
    apex.server.process("GET_EFFECTIVENESS", {
        x01: op_apl,
        x02: per_apl,
    x03: aut_ctrl
    }, {
    dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {            
        if(data.effectiveness) {
            ef_ctrl = data.value; 
            $s("P14_EFFECTIVENESS", ef_ctrl); 
            } else {
            console.error("No effectiveness was found for the given values.");
        }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("Error when obtaining control effectiveness:", errorThrown);
        }
    });
}


Thank you very much for your answer. Just as you say, I need to return the value of the Effectiveness column ('optimo', 'regular' or 'bueno'). I applied the changes to the PL/SQL and JavaScript code, but I still get the error: "No effectiveness was found for the given values."
I have the impression that the variables G_X01, G_X02 and G_X03 are not taking the values that I send them through JavaScript. But my programming knowledge is low and I cannot visualize the value that these variables are receiving.

Try to debug the parameters/values by alert() or console.log() on JavaScript level; inserting the data to a test/debug/temp table for SQL level
